# How to continuously read from a Java socket's inputstream despite blocking code?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm learning about Java Socket programming by creating a multiplayer card game application.  The client will handle both the game and a little chat window.

My client reads in instructions from the server from a loop like so:

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.startsWith("SOME_COMMAND") {
        // get necessary input from user
    } else if (line.startsWith("MESSAGE") {
        // tell EDT to update chat window
    }
}
```

My problem, though, is that getting input from the user pauses the loop, which stops the chat window from updating.

Is there a 'best practice' for this kind of problem?  I was thinking something along the lines of a filter, running in a separate thread, that processes messages and feeds non-messages back into a new stream that the main thread will loop through.

Comment: You need to test the result of `readLine()` for null before doing anything else, and stop looping when you get it. The usual way of writing the loop is `while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) ...`.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not do non-UI work in the EDT.** Always do stuff like reading from sockets, etc., from a separate thread. There are two ways to do this:

1. Have the non-EDT thread notify the EDT of updates, when they come in, using either `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` or `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait`. This is probably the best way to go for socket-polling.
2. Launch the non-EDT activity using `SwingWorker`. I personally consider `SwingWorker` to only be appropriate in response to some *action* by the user.